# Double tooltip on Email Settings page

Tags: bug, design, tooltips

There's tooltip doubling on [Email Settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) on the profile:

> [image: SO-SO]

That definitely looks weird.

Comment: Tooltip overflow..